# TYPO3/Typoscript : grid element undesirable anchors

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x, tx-gridelements

On my TYPO3 website (v6.2) I use CE backend Layout to allow my teammates to insert content easily. Problem :  tag are automatically generated and break all my layout (seems like html anchors to inserted content). This is what it looks like :

```
<ul id="timeline">

    <a id="c3837"></a>
    <li> CONTENT HERE</li>

    <a id="c3842"></a>
    <li> CONTENT HERE</li>

    <a id="c3845"></a>
    <li> CONTENT HERE</li>

</ul>
```

I tried several fix to remove them :

```
tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject.default >

tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap >

tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject.default.10.cObject.default.value =
```

... with no success.
Do you have any idea to solve this issue ?
Thanks !

Comment: you are trying to remove the CE default anchors, but I would assume the anchors are inserted from the gridelements CE. Have a look to the gridelement definition. (Fluid or typoscript)

Comment: Hi @BerndWilkeπφ, you are right : the <li> elements are generated by others gridelements CE but I tried to apply the same fixes on it.

Comment: if you can't influence the generation of these anchors with typoscript, they might be generated with fluid. if you use FSC instead of CSC look for the layout definitions of FSC

Comment: The children are 100% Typoscript : lib.gridelements.MYCHILD < .defaultGridSetup, and then tt_content.gridelements_pi1.20.10.setup.timeline_child < lib.gridelements.MYCHILD

Comment: By the way, the problem seems to occur only in one language, not the other one. May be a clue of problem ?

Comment: If you have translated records, two anchors are generated: one in the usual way for the uid of the record, but also another for the uid of the record in default language. In this way a link with the anchor to the uid of default lang would work in every language and could also be translated.

Comment: Hi Bernd, in my case the unwanted html anchor is "<a id="c2665"></a>" and 2665 is the uid of the translated record in the second language (the green frame in this picture : http://nsa39.casimages.com/img/2017/10/27/171027104858822829.jpg). Still don't understand how to remove it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED ! Thanks to [this stack overflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8417983/7286331).

I tried "tt_content.stdWrap.prepend >" and it works.