# How to remove anchors in a multilang TYPO3 9.5.5

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-9.x

I tried in my typoscript setup as [this stack overflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8417983/7286331) describes:

```
tt_content.stdWrap.dataWrap >
tt_content.stdWrap.prepend.dataWrap >
tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject.66.10 >
```

But nothing works in my TYPO3 9.5.5 multilang. In my language id=0 I do not have anchors (even without the tt_content.stdWrap). In my language id=1 I cannot get rid of it.

Do you got a solution or some helpful hint?

Comment: First, we need some info: Do you use the extension "css_styled_content" or "fluid_styled_content"? Depending on which one is used, the method to change the output of tt_content elements changes. Your snippet above usually only works with css_styled_content, which is no longer part of TYPO3 9 by default (was deprecated).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you use FSC:
in the layoutfile (`ext:fluid_styled_content/Resources/Private/Layouts/Default.html`) you will find the anchor conditioned by `{data._LOCALIZED_UID}`.
The default language has no anchor as the surrounding `div` has a matching id attribute.
(you can override it with your own layout file without condition)

if you use CSS:
go for the typoscript.

as CSC and FSC may vary with the TYPO3 versions snippets for removing the anchor may vary also.

Comment: I use FSC and your hint is very helpful and correct!